# Convert YYMMDD integer to YYYY-MM-DD date format on i5 DB

Tags: datetime, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Date is in a weird format of integer with YYMMDD and it is hard to integrate with other systems or write a query.

With the i5 system, here they designed the date to be an integer with YYMMDD format; sorting by the date in sql is a pain, CASE statement are too expensive to use.

```
date in 11-12-1988 is shown as 891112;
date in 01-01-2000 is shown as 101;
date in 09-01-2009 is shown as 90901;
date in 03-02-2019 is shown as 190302
```

Need best solution;  create a new date column and covert the existing integer date to date type; what is the best logic to handle it

Comment: I have never heard of the i5 database.  Are you sure you are not using a more common product such as MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: In order to offer a conversion solution, we need to know what year is used as the cut-off between `19yy` and `20yy`.

Comment: Also, I assume that the first line is a typo and should read:
`date in 11-12-1988 is shown as 881112;` not `891112` as in your post.

Comment: @daShier
yes ur right, its 881112
I am not sure what you mean by cut-off year. But just a heads up all my transactions start from 1988.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, FYR
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7J6S_6.2.0/com.ibm.websphere.wesb620.doc/doc/cins_db_i5.html

Comment: @JerrinJacob, your database is IBM's DB2, which is housed on an iSeries server. Similar to the set up I work with as a source system, although I've never run across this particular date convention.

Comment: Also, I can't speak for DB2 (I don't work in it, just pull data from it), but in SQL Server, if I left pad your values with leading zeros out to six characters, then explicitly `CAST` them as dates, the engine figures it out. Worth a try, maybe.

Comment: @EricBrandt, Thanks! Yes IBM DB2 is housed and forgot to mention it.
On an i5, the date was formatted as an int for whatever reason I cant understand why. DB2 also uses LPAD and I have already tried it but cant cast it to date directly. Need to change.

Well good news is I found the solution to get this date in YY-MM-DD format

`select           VARCHAR_FORMAT(DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(lpad(EMP_DT,6,0)),'YYMMDD')),'YY-MM-DD') as EMP_DT_N
from        EMPLOYEE`

but it doesnt work for YYYY-MM-DD. Dates prior to 2000 messes up, eg. if the emp_dt is 891112 then emp_dt_n is 2089-11-12.

Answer (score 0):

Based on cutoff year 1988, you can use following sql

```
select 
VARCHAR_FORMAT( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(
CHAR( case when EMP_DT < 880000 then emp_dt + 20000000 else emp_dt + 19000000 end),
'YYYYMMDD') ,'YYYY-MM-DD') as EMP_DT_N from EMPLOYEE
```